# Application built using Pega 7 Designer Studio running in IE11 compatibility mode in Edge

Tags: pega

Application built using Pega 7 Designer Studio running in IE11 compatibility mode in Edge. Is there any way we can disable this IE11 compatibility in Microsoft edge.

Comment: Go to Settings of Edge and search for `Internet Explorer compatibility`. Try disabling `Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode` option and check the result.

Comment: Application is still opening in Internet Explorer mode, even after disabling settings in Edge

Comment: Have you closed all Edge instatnces after settings change?

Answer (score 0):

**Disable IE mode on Microsoft Edge**

1. Open Microsoft Edge on Windows 10.
2. Click the Settings and More (ellipsis) button on the top-right
   corner.
3. Select the Settings option.
4. Click on Default browser.
5. Under the “Internet Explorer compatibility” section, turn off the
   “Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode” toggle
   switch.
6. Click the Restart button or Restart the Computer.